# Synergy setup broke on upgrade

Tags: synergy

I had synergy setup working fine with version 1.3.7, however I got a new computer and decided to set it up as well. Because the setup I was working with was ubuntu (server - dual monitors) mac (client) and the new computer (replacing the mac) was windows, I ended up updating everything to 1.4.10.

```
 ______ ______ ______
|  mac | ubu1 | ubu2 |
|______|______|______|
```

The problem is currently that dragging to the left of ubu1 causes the cursor on the mac to flicker briefly and then the cursor shows up at the bottom right corner of ubu2.

Here is my `.synergy.conf`

```
section: screens
    Andrews-Mac-Mini:
        ctrl = ctrl
        alt = meta
        super = alt 
    Andrew-Ubuntu:
end

section: links
    Andrew-Ubuntu:
        left = Andrews-Mac-Mini
    Andrews-Mac-Mini:
        right = Andrew-Ubuntu
end
```

And the output from `synergys -f`

```
NOTE: client "Andrews-Mac-Mini" has connected
INFO: switch from "Andrew-Ubuntu" to "Andrews-Mac-Mini" at 1679,451
INFO: leaving screen
INFO: screen "Andrew-Ubuntu" updated clipboard 0
INFO: screen "Andrew-Ubuntu" updated clipboard 1
INFO: switch from "Andrews-Mac-Mini" to "Andrew-Ubuntu" at 2398,833
INFO: entering screen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a sort of work around for the problem. I plugged a real mouse (instead of using my laptop trackpad) into the server and it started working. Even now that I have it working, if I use the track pad and slide it to the mac the cursor disappears and doesn't do anything, but the keyboard still registers. Then I fiddle the mouse a bit and it shows up on the server, and I can use the mouse onto the mac again. Looks like a bug in synergy.